# Attach multiple images into html email in Python

Tags: python, html

I have the following code to attach all the images from a folder to send html email. The images are part of the html file so they have to be attached. Given there're 10 images, I'm wondering how to do it in a more efficient manner.

```
fp = open('newsletter/bar_chart.png', 'rb')
msgImage1 = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
msgImage1.add_header('Content-ID', '<bar_chart>')
msgRoot.attach(msgImage1)

fp = open('newsletter/scatter_plot.png', 'rb')
msgImage2 = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<scatter_plot>')
msgRoot.attach(msgImage2)

fp = open('newsletter/image3.png', 'rb')
msgImage3 = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
msgImage3.add_header('Content-ID', '<image3>')
msgRoot.attach(msgImage3)

fp = open('newsletter/image4.png', 'rb')
msgImage4 = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
msgImage4.add_header('Content-ID', '<image4>')
msgRoot.attach(msgImage4)
```

Comment: simply create list with file names and use `for`-loop to run the same code for all values from list. And if you need different `<image4>` then use `f-string` like `f"<image{number}>`  with `enumerate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply keep filenames as list and use `for`-loop to repeate the same code for different items from list.

To have different `Content-ID` you can simply use `f-string` like `f"<image{number}>` with `enumerate()`.

```py
filenames = [
    'newsletter/bar_chart.png',
    'newsletter/scatter_plot.png',
    'newsletter/image3.png',
    'newsletter/image4.png',
]

for number, name in enumerate(filenames, 1):
    fp = open(name, 'rb')
    msg_image = MIMEImage(fp.read())   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
    fp.close()
    msg_image.add_header('Content-ID', f'<image{number}>')
    msg_root.attach(msg_image)
```

This way you can get filenames from:

- file
- database
- `os.listdir('newsletter')`
- `glob.glob('newsletter/*.png')`
- command line - `python.exe script.py name1 name2` and `filenames = sys.argv[1:]`

---

Eventually you can create list with tuples `(filename, content_id)`

In list you can use string `"<image4>"` or you can use string `"image4"` and later use `f-string` to add `< >` - `f"<{content_id}>"`.

```py
filenames = [
    ('newsletter/bar_chart.png', 'bar_chart'),
    ('newsletter/scatter_plot.png', 'scatter_plot'),
    ('newsletter/image3.png', 'image3'),
    ('newsletter/image4.png', 'image4'),
]

for name, content_id in filenames:
    fp = open(name, 'rb')
    msg_image = MIMEImage(fp.read())   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
    fp.close()
    msg_image.add_header('Content-ID', f'<{content_id}>')
    msg_root.attach(msg_image)
```

Eventually you could use name like `newsletter/bar_chart.png` to create `content_id`.

```
content_id = name.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
```

It gives `bar_chart`

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: You're amazing! I have learnt so much from your answer. Thanks again!